# pread() compatiblitiy on Android platform

Tags: android, android-ndk

Has anyone information about pread() compatibility on the android platform, please? As far as I know there was a problem with this call some version ago:

- [Android 2.1 file i/o: pread fails with errno 22 (EINVAL, Invalid argument)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038697/android-2-1-file-i-o-pread-fails-with-errno-22-einval-invalid-argument)
- https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/issues/detail?id=100#c8

Are there any information about that problem? Is it a bug in the OS kernel or bionic (libc) or android-ndk? Was it fixed?

Comment: why this interest you? you have a problem with it now?

Comment: The linked SO post is with regard to I/O on a /sdcard, which has been a little wonky in some releases.  I vaguely recall something about FUSE emulation of the filesystem causing odd problems.

Comment: I'm going to use it in a native library for android. And I would like to be sure about it workability.